# Invalid Argument given foreach loop php

Tags: php, file-upload, foreach

I am trying to post an image to my websites file directory via PHP. This exact code works for another page on the site but I am having an issue with getting it to work on this page:

```
    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
        $errors= array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']); $i++){

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$i];  
            if($file_size > 2097152){
                $errorMessage2.="File size must be less than 2 MB";
            }   

            $img_dir="../images/property_directory";
            if(is_dir($img_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$img_dir", 0700, true);    // Create directory if it does not exist
            }

            if(is_dir("$img_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$img_dir/". $file_name);
                $filePath[$i] = "$img_dir/" . $file_name;   
            }else{// rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$img_dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ; 
               $filePath[$i] = "$img_dir/" . $file_name.time();      
           }
      }
   }

if(empty($errorMessage2)){
    $filePathArr = "";
    foreach ($filePath as $v) {
       $filePathArr .= "$v ";
    }
```

The foreach loop is throwing an error saying "invalid argument supplied for foreach()" I don't think the array is empty because I am supplying it with a file using the files[] button.

Comment: Why not verify what $filePath contains with a good ol` fashion `var_dump($filePath);` just before the foreach?

Comment: @devlincarnate hmm, it appears to be "NULL" which is quite strange

Comment: Are you sure `$_FILES['files']` is set? If it's not set, you won't go into the first loop, so you'll never set `$filePath`. `if (empty($errorMessage2))` should probably be inside `if(isset($_FILES['files']))`.

Comment: @Barmar This is my code for the button which I think is correct as it is working on another page I am using:

    `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" class="fileUpload"/>`

Comment: Do you see all the data in `var_dump($_FILES)`? Does the form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in you for loop. You should count `$_FILES['files']['name']` but not `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']`. See the code below:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
....
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter which one he counts? All the entries in `$_FILES['files']` should be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience. For me the issue was with the HTML form element.

I initially had name of the file type as "images"

```
<input type="file" name="images" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

This would work if I was only dealing with one image. However, since I am uploading multiple images, I had to change it to "images[]" as an array.

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```